# Jetbrains Plugin Custom TextEditor Rendering

Tags: intellij-plugin

How does one go about extending the jetbrains texteditor in a plugin to replace the text/characters/tokens with images/sprites?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the current version of IntelliJ IDEA (2016.3). The only possibility is to use the [EditorInlay API](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/Inlay.java) to insert custom-drawn fragments between characters in the editor.

Comment: The lack of existing plugins which do that may have been a clue.